# numpy mask un-shaped N-dimensional array

Tags: numpy, shapes, mask, dimension

Here is a Numpy array I would like to mask (note it is not a strict 2D array):

a = array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)

This seems impossible however. I would like to understand why, and possibly how to treat this kind of example, where I get a mask from a values to apply it to another array with the same shape.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is an object dtype array, containing 3 elements (which happen to be arrays themselves):

```
In [94]: a = np.array([np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), np.array([0, 1]), np.array([0,
    ...:  1, 2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
In [95]: a
Out[95]: array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
In [96]: a.shape
Out[96]: (3,)
In [97]: a[1]
Out[97]: array([0, 1])
```

What do you mean by `mask`?

I can apply a boolean index to it:

```
In [99]: a[np.array([True,False,True])]
Out[99]: array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

`a==np.array([0,1])` produces a warning and `False`;  In general `==` (and other comparison test) does not work well with object dtype arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I think my problem is larger and I just wanted to create a N-dimensional array with multiple row sizes, which is not the Numpy essence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to use Pandas DataFrames that can hold missing values. In your case you could do something like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([aa[0].tolist(), aa[1].tolist(), aa[2].tolist()])
>>> df.transpose()
>>> df

   0  1    2    3    4
0  0  1  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  0  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  0  1  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

DataFrames are very powerful and they have more appropriate methods than Numpy arrays when you think of something that is more like a spreadsheet than like a matrix.